# Magento2 unit test error "Error: Call to a member function getDirectoryWrite() on null"

Tags: phpunit, magento2

Magento2 unit test for block file for admin grid extending Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended is giving error "Error: Call to a member function getDirectoryWrite() on null"

added below mocks, still error continues.

```
$this->_filesystem = $this->createMock(Filesystem::class);
$this->_directory = $this->createMock(DirectoryWrite::class);
$this->_filesystem->method('getDirectoryWrite')->willReturn($this->_directory);
```

Can anyone help here?